# Get value from uncomputed css style with javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a small question concerning css styles and javascript / jquery. Lets say i define the following css style.

```
.myStile { padding: 5px }
```

Now I'd like to access the property of padding while not writing an html element to the document. I came up with the following idea which only works with Firefox (IE and Chrome say NaN)

```
var div = $('<div class="myStile />');
var padding = parseInt(div.css('padding-left'), 10);
```

is there a way to make this work in IE and Chrome (well trident and webkit I guess) as well? I know that one's able to read whole css files via javascript (and get the class, the properties and so on ...), but that seems to be a bit overkill.

Comment: hallo dänu! here is a question i asked a while ago. I think you can get your answers there! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285033/read-hover-pseudo-class-with-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks meo for your comment. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285033/read-hover-pseudo-class-with-javascript) answers the question. [Here's a google find](http://www.lipfert-malik.de/webdesign/tutorial/bsp/getcomputedstyle-4all.html) which answers the "other browsers than chrome, firefox, safari" issue.