# Why doesn't getComputedStyle work with pseudo classes like :hover?

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors

The function `window.getComputedStyle` is supposed to be able to get the computed style of pseudo classes like :hover, according to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle).

It's also explained as an answer in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1285212/813759)

But as the last comment says in that question, in fact it doesn't work at all, it just returns the normal style, not the :hover style. You can see for yourself in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ukjES/). The alert returns the red color, not the green one.

The [documentation on developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) also has an example, but that doesn't work either - see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5bYsG/).

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7756455/813759) the answerer states in a comment that it won't work at all, but without giving an explanation.

Could it be that the stylesheet has to be fully rendered before the function returns the correct value? I've tried setting some delays, but nothing seems to work.

I've tried the latest Firefox, Chrome and IE browsers. Does anybody know why this function is not working as expected?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle(element[, pseudoElt]);
```

where `pseudoElt` is *"a string specifying the pseudo-**element** to match"*. A pseudo-**element** is something like `::before` or `::after`, those are elements which are generated by CSS styles. `:hover`, `:visited` or other similar effects are pseuodo-**classes**. They won't create new elements but apply specialized class styles to the element.

It's not possible to get the computed style of a pseudo-class, at least not with `getComputedStyle`. You can however traverse through the CSS rules and try to find a fitting selector, but I won't recommend you to do this, since some browsers won't follow the DOM-Level-2-Style rules and you would have to check which rule will affect your specific element:

```css
/* Style */
p a:hover{ color:yellow; background:black;}
p > a:hover{ color:green; background:white;}
p > a+a:hover{ color:fuchsia; background:blue;}
```

```js
// JS
var i,j, sel = /a:hover/;
for(i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; ++i){
    for(j = 0; j < document.styleSheets[i].cssRules.length; ++j){    
        if(sel.test(document.styleSheets[i].cssRules[j].selectorText)){
            console.log(
                document.styleSheets[i].cssRules[j].selectorText,
                document.styleSheets[i].cssRules[j].style.cssText
            );
        }
    }
}
```

```
Result:
p a:hover color: yellow; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% black; 
p > a:hover color: green; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% white;
p > a + a:hover color: fuchsia; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% blue;
```

See also:

- MDN: [`getComputedStyle` examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle#Use_with_pseudo-elements)
- W3C: [CSS2: 5.10 Pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pseudo-elements)
- SO: [Setting CSS pseudo-class rules from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311052/setting-css-pseudo-class-rules-from-javascript)

Comment: This makes things absolutely clear. Damn those pseudo-classes! Great to use, but it's a mystery that you can't use them programmatically.

Comment: `document.styleSheets[].cssRules` is not available for stylesheets loaded from external sources (ie `<link>`)

Answer (score 3):

Note that there is a way to do this at least for Chrome with the remote debugging port turned on. Basically you need to use a WebSocket, connect to the remote debugger url, then issue the following commands:

```
send  { id: 1, method: "Inspector.enable" }
send  { id: 2, method: "DOM.enable" }
send  { id: 3, method: "CSS.enable" }
send  { id: 4, method: "DOM.getDocument" }
send  { id: 5, method: "DOM.querySelector", params: { nodeId: 1, selector: <<whatever you want>> } }
nodeId = response.result.nodeId
send  { id: 6, method: "CSS.forcePseudoState", params: { nodeId:, forcedPseudoClasses: [ "hover" <<or whatever>> ] } }
```

Then you can use the regular getComputedStyle, or the CSS.getComputedStyleForNode debugger API.