# How can I get element:hover style?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need help, I want to get element:hover all styles.
For example:

```
<style type="text/css">
a {color: red;}
a:hover {color: blue;}
</style>
```

Using jquery we can find "a" element default style:

```
$('a').css('color');
```

and it will be return as string: "red";

But now I want to get pseudo styles, like this:

```
$('a:hover').css('color');
```

and it will be return "undefined", but we need "blue".

Please help me solve this problem...

---

Comment: Javascript doesn't support pseudo classes

Comment: Seems like this was 4 years ago yet I ended up here and it is marked as a duplicate but doesn't say what it is a duplicate of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pure Javascript does it!

```
function getCssPropertyForRule(rule, prop) {
        var sheets = document.styleSheets;
        var slen = sheets.length;
        for(var i=0; i<slen; i++) {
            var rules = document.styleSheets[i].cssRules;
            var rlen = rules.length;
            for(var j=0; j<rlen; j++) {
                if(rules[j].selectorText == rule) {
                    return rules[j].style[prop];
                }
            }
        }
    }

 alert("Hovered Colour is "+getCssPropertyForRule('a:hover', 'color'));
```

Here is a Working example
[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3FYz6/)

Comment: This only works if you happen to know the exact selector used in the CSS...

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I used this in combination with another function to change the ```a``` & ```a:hover``` colors. I needed to do thus via a button (for my web app), so I couldn't rely on CSS alone.

Answer (score 1):

That is because there is no element `a` with type `:hover`. So it would always return a `undefined`.

And I don't think you can get the pseudo class properties using jQuery or JavaScript until you get all the styles and then check for the element's property in that file.

Answer (score -1):

```
var color = window.getComputedStyle(
    document.querySelector('a'), ':hover'
).getPropertyValue('color')
```

Check [this link](http://davidwalsh.name/pseudo-element) for extra information.

Comment: This doesn't work for hover

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495535/why-doesnt-getcomputedstyle-work-with-pseudo-classes-like-hover

Answer (score -1):

You can use `.hover()` function instead. http://api.jquery.com/hover/

```
$( "a.foo" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).css( 'color','red' );
  }, function() {
    $( this ).css( 'color','blue');
  }
);
```