# Test for pseudo class using Jest and React-test-renderer

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-test-renderer

I have a few hover pseudo classes in css and want to run a test and check if they are behaving properly. Is this possible with Jest? Apologies for my lack of knowledge here I'm only a day in using Jest.

Css:

```
.my-btn--lg.my-btn--brand.hover, .my-btn--md.my-btn--brand:hover {
    background-color: #ac0000;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems it's impossible.

I'm not sure if jsdom provides appropriate version of `window.getComputedStyle` but anyway there is no way to check for styles based on pseudoclass so far. `jest` as generic test runner and `react-test-renderer` that "just" compiles JSX into HTMLElements knows nothing about pseudoclass/hover state.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/11495671/2071697 for details how you can parse CSS by yourselves to find `:hover` rule(but I believe it is not efficient way to compose unit tests)

Comment: Ah, yeah seems trivial...Thanks for the link 