# IE9 get hover color javascript

Tags: javascript, css, scripting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Read :hover pseudo class with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285033/read-hover-pseudo-class-with-javascript)

Is there a way to get the hover color of an element using javascript??

EDIT: See the socalled "duplicate answer" for my retort.

Comment: I want to know how to get the hover color of an object. I want to do this with javascript.

Comment: I'm not a javascript programmer but I need this for a project. Is it so hard to tell me how to do this instead of linking to a "solution" I don't understand???

Comment: hey get on, people here do that a lot.I am new too. Post a new question and ask properly. try on your own and post some codes. ok???

Comment: in css
#id.hover{color:red}
in jQuery 
$('#id').hover(function(){this.addClass('hover')},function(){this.removeClass('hover')})

using pure javascript

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17257/discussion-between-i-love-php-and-c-tz)

Comment: If the answer in the duplicate question is not suitable in your situation, you can explain this. The example shown is very simple, but you need at least a basic understanding of JavaScript / DOM. This is something we cannot help with / teach you here and if you came here with the expectation to get working code without understanding it, then I'm sorry, but this simply won't work.

Comment: How can I re-open this question to answer it? I've found a solution.

Comment: Felix King, I've spend some time putting a function together which actualy does something, instead of the code of the so called duplicate, which doesn't even work it seems.

Comment: @C-TZ if this is the case post your answer in the duplicate answers. leave a disclaimer that it was specifically for this question if anyone needs to contest it.

Comment: OP has a point here, the answer was not on the duplicate question (at least not a complete one). I just added one there.