# Can Javascript read from an element's :hover state in CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my page, I have several divs which change their background image when the cursor hovers over them. The setup is akin to this:

```css
#myDiv1 {
  background-image: url("http://example.com/firstImage.png");
}
#myDiv1:hover {
  background-image: url("http://example.com/secondImage.png");
}
#myDiv2 {
  background-image: url("http://example.com/thirdImage.png");
}
#myDiv2:hover {
  background-image: url("http://example.com/fourthImage.png");
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv1">Hello</div>
<div id="myDiv2">World</div>
```

I would like to read the URL of each div's `:hover` background using JavaScript, without needing to invoke the `:hover` state itself. Are there any selectors that can retrieve that data?

Comment: check .hover event https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: @Amr Elgarhy It looks to me like the .hover event is used to fire functions instead of retrieve data.  I don't think it's what I'm looking for.

Comment: @NickD no, it will not fire the hover,  it will watch for hover, 'to be executed when the mouse pointer enters and leaves the elements'

Comment: you can iterate the cssRules on the styleSheet object, which lets you see the selector (including pseudos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** This answer doesn't work and there is no 100% accurate way to get this information. The second parameter to [`Window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) is a pseudo-element and `:hover` is a pseudo-class. See the duplicate question for more information: [Read :hover pseudo class with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285033/read-hover-pseudo-class-with-javascript)

<strike>You can use [`Window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) like this:</strike>

```js
var style = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("#myDiv1"), ":hover").getPropertyValue("background-image");
alert(style);
```

```css
#myDiv1 {
  background-image: url("http://example.com/firstImage.png");
}
#myDiv1:hover {
  background-image: url("http://example.com/secondImage.png");
}
#myDiv2 {
  background-image: url("http://example.com/thirdImage.png");
}
#myDiv2:hover {
  background-image: url("http://example.com/fourthImage.png");
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv1">Hello</div>
<div id="myDiv2">World</div>
```